# git on windows remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

I have a 2MB of files. I created a repository. I setup the upstream url on my local dev environment. Everything goes well when I pull down or clone the empty repository I created until I try to add the 2MB of files and push them to the remote end.

I thought at first it might be the problem of the repository provider. I tried with bitbucket, gitlab and then finally github. But the same error :( so disappointing. Here is what I see in all the three cases.

```
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 2.16 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried using the https protocol instead of ssh.
I also tried to extend the postBuffer setting. But none of them helped.

I tried suggestions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855009/4688650) and I found the following error:

```
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.30.252.130: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote enfatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
d hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:merhawifissehaye/gunadefault.git'
```

I also tried the accepted [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection/142430#142430) from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection) and got the following error:

```
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
packet_write_poll: Connection to 192.30.252.128: Broken pipe
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Bfatal: roken pipe
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:merhawifissehaye/gunadefault.git'
```

The only difference  see from the previous error is the Bfatal error. I don't know if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

The [atlassian help page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=693897332) mentions (for a clone, but that applies to other network command as well):

> Error code 56 indicates a curl receive error of `CURLE_RECV_ERROR` which means there was some issue that prevented the data from being received during the clone process.
>   Typically **this is caused by a network setting, firewall, VPN client, or anti-virus that is terminating the connection before all data has been transferred**.

You can see more with ([Windows syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824572/6309)):

```
 cmd /C /V "set "GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1" && git push"
```

Check (for a short test) if deactivating (very temporarily)  your anti-virus would allow the git command to proceed.

One workaround is to use an [ssh url](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html).

Comment: I tried your cmd command, a normal windows cmd showed up. I pushed from there. But the same error. I deactivated my antivirus, but no luck. I have setup my ssh and trying with ssh url has the same error.

Comment: I have edited my question with the error I got after trying your suggestion

Comment: I had stumbled upon that question previously. I tried it now too. Doesn't seem to change anything. I have updated the question with the error I found.

Comment: @MerhawiFissehaye Does that issue persists on another computer? From another network?