# Executing Command with "cmd" That Contains Spaces Through Git-Bash?

Tags: windows, cmd, git-bash

I'm trying to execute a command with git-bash using cmd. I need to pass the command for it to execute. The problem is I need to pass the path of the batch file into the command and it has spaces. I can't seem to be able to pass quotes to "cmd" in a way that it will understand it.

`cmd //C "c:\Program Files (x86)\another path\file.bat args && echo done"`

That will give me an error:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

If I try using single quotes then it passes a literal backslash to cmd.

`cmd //C '"c:\Program Files (x86)\another path\file.bat" args && echo done'`

Which will give me the error the same error but show the backslashes:

`'\"c:\Program Files (x86)\another path\file.bat\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CMD /C, see "[Bash in Git for Windows: Weirdness when running a command with CMD.exe /C with args](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21907301/6309)"

Try using a Unix-style path, within double-quotes

```
$ CMD //C "/c/Program Files (x86)/Opera/New folder/a.bat"
```

(no `&& echo done`)

Tested with git version 2.11.0.windows.1 on Windows 10.

Note: For simple commands, you don't need a `CMD /C` to execute a bat from a git bash session. In that case, you can escape spaces and parenthesis:

```
vonc@vonc MINGW64 /c/Users/vonc
$ /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Test/New\ folder/a.bat
```

The OP adds in the comments:

> I want the environment variables to only exist on the one instance of `cmd`. I don't want it to actually set the environment variables in bash.
>   Which is why the "`&&`" is necessary, as the other command would rely on those variables. That's the only command I need to rely on them for.
>   `cmd /C "C:/path to/vcvarsall.bat && echo %LIB%"` should print the env variable set by the batch file.
>   Then in git-bash I want `echo $LIB` to print nothing after executing the command.

`echo %LIB%` is tricky because the CMD session would use the echo from Git, instead of the `echo` builtin CMD shell command.
But [chaining multiple command in a `CMD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824572/6309) (adapted here for a Git bash session) is done with:

```
cmd //V //C "C:/path to/vcvarsall.bat&&set myvar"
```

`set myvar` will display the value set for `myvar` by the bat script.
And yet, back in the bash session, an `echo ${myvar}` would not display anything.

Comment: The batch script doesn't work in git-bash though. If it helps it's vcvarall.bat for visual studio.

Comment: Not really an error so much as the batch script doesn't do anything, which it is suppose to add variables to the environment. I wanted to use cmd as it works in there, but I need the "&&" bit as the program has to run in that environment with those symbols loaded. This would also be preferred as I don't want the environment variables loaded into the current bash as they cause conflict.

Comment: @user240713 Add variable to the environment? That would not work in a CMD /C session: it opens a CMD, then quit. Any environment variable set is lost. Could you wrap all you need to do in a .bat which would call vcvarall.bat  and does the rest, as opposed to mix and match Windows and bash commands?

Comment: Yes I want the environment variables to only exist on the one instance of cmd. I don't want it to actually set the environment variables in bash. Which is why the "&&" is necessary. As the other command would rely on those variables. That's the only command I need to rely on them for. `cmd /C "C:/path to/vcvarsall.bat && echo %LIB%"`. Should print the env variable set by the batch file. Then in git-bash I want `echo $LIB` to print nothing after executing the command.

Comment: @user240713 easy (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31824572/6309): `cmd /V /C "C:/path to/vcvarsall.bat&& echo !LIB!"`: note the `/V` (enable delayed expansion), the lack of space between `.bat` and `&&`, and the `!LIB!` instead of `%LIB%`.

Comment: Running that from git-bash I get `bash: !LIB!: event not found`.

Comment: @user240713 I just tested it in a Git bash session, and indeed the `echo` does not work (because it takes the `echo` from Git instead of the builtin CMD `echo`). But if you replace `echo !LIB!` by `set LIB`, you will see that `LIB` is properly valued.

Comment: @user240713 I have edited the answer to include the comments here, for the solution to be more visible.

Answer (score 0):

And another simple way is to navigate to the directory(using cd command) that contains that file and then run the command and pass the filename.

Comment: You don't need that: you can directly reference the script, without using CMD or changing path. See my answer.