# How to pass the path to custom .env file when using the Node.js TypeORM CLI?

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Assume that .env file name is building mode dependent.
How we can specify it when using the TypeORM CLI?
It should be something like:

```
typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:run/
   -d ./01-Source/DataBase/TypeORM_DataSource.ts/
   --env ".env.local.generated"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TypeORM documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d8a2e3730f12bb2b8e521635e176a284594121f3/docs/zh_CN/using-ormconfig.md?plain=1#L139) says:

> ### Which configuration file Typeorm uses
>
> Sometimes you may wish to use multiple configurations in different formats. When calling `getConnectionOptions()` or trying to use `createConnection()` without connection options, Typeorm will try to load configurations in the following order:
>
> 1. From environment variables. Typeorm will try to load the `.env` file using dotEnv if it exists. Typeorm will use this method if the environment variables `TYPEORM_CONNECTION` or `TYPEORM_URL` are set.
> 2. From `ormconfig.env`.
> 3. From another `ormconfig.[format]` file, in this order: `[js,ts,json]`.

That means, TypeORM supports loading configuration from different sources, including environment variables and various ormconfig files.
However, the built-in support for `.env` files in TypeORM is limited to loading only the default `.env` file in the root directory of your project.

In your specific case, you want to load a custom `.env` file (e.g., `.env.local.generated`) instead of the default `.env` file, which is not part of TypeORM built-in support for specifying a custom `.env` file path.

So you might need to consider [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) (`npm install dotenv`), that loads environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`.

By preloading `dotenv` and specifying the custom `.env` file path using the dotenv_config_path environment variable, we can load the environment variables from the custom `.env` file before TypeORM starts.
This way, when TypeORM looks for the environment variables, they are already loaded into `process.env`, and TypeORM can use them as expected.

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS="-r dotenv/config" dotenv_config_path=".env.local.generated" \
typeorm migration:run -d ./01-Source/DataBase/TypeORM_DataSource.ts
```

On Windows, as I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824572/6309):

```bash
cmd /v /c "set "NODE_OPTIONS=-r dotenv/config" && set "dotenv_config_path=.env.local.generated" && typeorm migration:run -d "./01-Source/DataBase/TypeORM_DataSource.ts""
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dotenv which makes your work done

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Create a .env file in the root of your project:

```
S3_BUCKET="YOURS3BUCKET"
SECRET_KEY="YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE"
```

Code--

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it is working
s3.getBucketCors({Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET}, function(err, data) {})
```

Dotenv provides 2 functions--

1.Config-

```
const result = dotenv.config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

console.log(result.parsed)
```

Optional-

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })
require('dotenv').config({ debug: process.env.DEBUG })
require('dotenv').config({ override: true })
```

2.Parse-

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const buf = Buffer.from('BASIC=basic')
const config = dotenv.parse(buf) // will return an object
console.log(typeof config, config) // object { BASIC : 'basic' }
```

Optional-

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const buf = Buffer.from('hello world')
const opt = { debug: true }
const config = dotenv.parse(buf, opt)
// expect a debug message because the buffer is not in KEY=VAL form
```